# Resizing image in QT 5.15

Tags: image, qt, toolbar, google-cloud-storage

[Toolbar view in application currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ov5U.png)
I need to make the image in the toolbar bigger so that one can see the text.

```
Code so far:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZASn.png)
```

So, how would I go about resizing the image so that the text in it is clearly visible. Right now the image is too small in the toolbar. Thank you

Comment: Add your code as text not an image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

fillMode is your issue here, if you comment that out it will not resize to fit in the (small) height of the toolbar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).